# Google webmaster tool show error in sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I have submitted a sitemap to google webmaster tool. It shows an error:

> This is not a valid URL. Please correct it and resubmit.
>   Parent tag: url
>   Tag: loc
>   Line: 2

My sitemap.xml file link is:
[Sitemap.xml](http://freemovieshub.com/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. One of location tag was empty in sitemap.xml